# Web App that Compares User Credentials to /etc/shadow

Tags: security, unix, authentication

I want to securely allow a web application to verify user credentials by checking the users entered info with /etc/shadow (unless there is some other solution). Is there any safe way to do this? It wouldn't be too hard to get it to run as root and then have it check the file and run the designated hash algorithm and salt string but this is eliminating the whole reason for having the salt value in the hash and severely reduces the security of the system.

So is there any utility or better way to try and have a web application verify my unix credentials or safe way to access /etc/shadow?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, the authentication would be handled by the web server (container managed authentication). For example, in Tomcat, this would authenticate against an active directory:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm"
            debug="99"
            connectionName="CN=Our Users,OU=Accounts,DC=domainds,DC=com"
            connectionPassword="S0mePassWord"
            connectionURL="ldap://192.168.1.0:389"
            alternateURL="ldap://192.168.1.1:389"
            referrals="follow"
            userBase="OU=User Accounts,DC=domainds,DC=com"
            userSearch="(sAMAccountName={0})"
            userSubtree="true"
            roleBase="OU=User Roles,DC=domainds,DC=com"
            roleName="cn"
            roleSearch="(member={0})"
            roleSubtree="true"
            />
```

To do what you ask is not impossible, but be careful not to pass an unencrypted password as a parameter because those might be visible on some forms of the "ps" command.

For a script (probably you would need more than one) to do what you ask, it might expose you to security issues, especially if you are not aware of all the intricacies of code injection into scripts. (Same idea a SQL injection, except it's for scripts.)